# Problema con envio de datos por ajax (laravel)

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy enviando un dato por ajax con type : 'post', pero me genera error, cuando lo cambio a type : 'get', los datos si son recibidos en success. Este es el codigo.

**Ajax**

```
$('.QuestionList-item').on('click', function() {
        $('.Question').show();
        $('.QuestionList').removeClass('col-12').addClass('col-6');

        var param = {
            '_token'  : $('#token').val(),
            'userid': $(this).children('.clientName').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url     :  "{{route('questionDetail')}}",
            type    :  'post',
            dataType:  'json',
            data    :   param,
            success :   function (data) {
                alert('send');
            },
            error   :   function() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
    <article class="QuestionList-item row middle">
        <figure class="stateIcon">
            <svg title="checkmark" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="svgIcon detailsTitle-checkmarkSvg"><polygon points="30,5.077 26,2 11.5,22.5 4.5,15.5 1,19 12,30"></polygon></svg>
        </figure>
        <span class="ProductName">{{$question->product->name}}</span>
        <input class="clientName" type="text" value="{{$question->user_id}}">
    </article>
@endforeach
```

**Ruta**

```
Route::post('preguntas', [
'uses' => 'QuestionController@questionDetail',
'as' => 'questionDetail',
'middleware' => 'VerifyProvider']);
```

**Controlador**

```
function questionDetail(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()){
        $user = User::find(1);
        return response()->json([$user]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya solucioné el error. 
Para enviar por el metodo post, en laravel es necesario el token. Se me olvidó ponerlo en blade.

```
<input id="token" type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Luego de iniciar el evento .on pones esto:

```
event.preventDefault();
$.ajaxSetup({headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')}  })
```